# quasar_src_plugins_Notify_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.create is not a function

Tags: function, webpack, single-page-application, notify, quasar

I upgrade my app from Quasar 1 to Quasar 2. When I run the app, the above error appears. What's wrong?

My run command:

`quasar dev`

I use Quasar 2.5.5 Node 16.14.0

Answer (score 0):

Add the plugin 'Notify' in the file quasar.conf.js.

```
  // Quasar plugins
  plugins: [
    'Notify'
  ]
```